# Determine whether WM_KEYDOWN's wParam is printable

Tags: c++, winapi, key, ascii

I am trying to detect non-printable characters in my window's `WM_KEYDOWN` message, but research so far has yielded no results. I have tried the following methods:

- 1: `iscntrl(wParam)`, which does not work for the arrow keys
- 2: `ischar(wParam)`, which also does not work for the same keys
- 3: `ToAscii(wParam, MapVirtualKey(wParam, 0) ...)`, which still does not work

IMO the third method should work because arrow keys are not on any ASCII or Unicode tables.

The thing is I would like to send to my event handlers both the keycode and the character. Since `WM_CHAR` is posted *after* `WM_KEYDOWN`, I would like to just send the key in `WM_KEYDOWN` if it is not printable (because `WM_CHAR` would not be sent to the window so I cannot do it there).

Thanks

Comment: The argument to MapVirtualKey() is wrong, use MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR instead.  Not using WM_CHAR is unwise, nothing you can't fix with your message loop.

Comment: Sometimes WM_CHAR can't be used because a dialog's controls handle key messages and the dialog never receives it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that most of the keys which are generally considered "printable" are contiguous, why not just use a few *if* statements to decide how you want to handle them?  In WM_KEYDOWN, decide whether a key is "printable" or not, and if it is, fire it off to WM_CHAR.

The functions that you're researching aren't designed for this specific purpose, so ironically, you might spend more time researching them than it would take to make an ad-hoc solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your method #3 should work for this. In `PreTranslateMessage`, handling `WM_KEYDOWN`:

```
BYTE keyboardState[256];
::GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
WORD ascii;
int len = ::ToAscii(wParam, (lParam >> 16) & 0xFF, keyboardState, &ascii, 0);
if (len == 1)
{
    /* it's printable */
    printf("%c", ascii & 0xFF); 
}
```